# What are the time goals for survival medals?

Tags: serious-sam-3-bfe

How long do you need to survive on each of the two official survival maps in order to get a medal, or a gold medal?

All I know at the moment is that two minutes nineteen doesn't cut it on either map. :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The game does give an answer to this question... but I lack good enough software to [zoom in and enhance](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vxq9yj2pVWk) on [this screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/74OCA.jpg). You can't zoom in and you also don't get notifications as you play.

So here's what the answer must (?) be, in plain sight:

```
LEVEL                SINGLE PLAYER            COOPERATIVE
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Death Canyon        Bronze    4:00          Bronze   5:00
                    Silver    5:00          Silver   6:00
                    Gold      6:00          Gold     7:00

Deserted            Bronze    3:30          Bronze   6:00
                    Silver    4:30          Silver   8:00
                    Gold      5:30          Gold    10:00
```